# Subscribe to PairCreated Event on PancakeSwap's Factory Contract

Tags: bsc, pancakeswap

I'm using ethersjs and bscscan to try and subscribe to the PairCreated event on the factory contract of PancakeSwap.

I do the following and run it with node:

```
const ethers = require('ethers');
const { BscscanProvider } = require("@ethers-ancillary/bsc");
const addresses = {
    WBNB: "0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c",
    factory: "0xcA143Ce32Fe78f1f7019d7d551a6402fC5350c73",
}

const mnemonic = ""

api_token = ""
const provider = new BscscanProvider(null, api_token)
const wallet = ethers.Wallet.fromMnemonic(mnemonic);
const account = wallet.connect(provider)

const factory = new ethers.Contract(
    addresses.factory,
    [
      'event PairCreated(address indexed token0, address indexed token1, address pair, uint)',
      'function balanceOf(address owner) view returns (uint256)'
    ],
    account
);

console.log("Started.")

 factory.on("PairCreated", async (token0, token1, addressPair, length) => {
  console.log("found new token")
})
```

The script runs forever but the listener never gets triggered while it should get triggered because if I go to bscscan to check, the event basically fires all the time.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine with web3 py.

event_filter = contract.events.PairCreated.createFilter(fromBlock='latest')